# If/Else Guidance

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Basically I am doing some AD Provisioning and wanted to come up with a script that would not only check the groups created but when changed as well, and I have been successful at accomplishing this but not getting to do it all in one script.

In other words give me the Group results of whencreated if it equals none then give me the whenchanged results.

Here is what I have so far with no real understanding of where to start can anyone shed some light on this please.

```
#Imports AD
Import-Module activedirectory

# Checks the accounts created with in the week.The days can be modified for needs.
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties whenCreated |
  Where-Object {$_.whenCreated -ge ((Get-Date).AddDays(-07)).Date} 

# Checks the accounts changed with in the week, and creates a text file
# of the output. The days can be modified for needs.
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties whenChanged |
  Where-Object {$_.whenChanged -ge ((Get-Date).AddDays(-07)).Date} |
  Out-File C:\PScript\ChangedADGroups.txt
```

So i have tweaked it up a bit with the help of some of you here which i appreciate.

As it stands the script goes:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$CreatedThreshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date
$ChangedThreshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date

$CreatedGroups = @(Get-ADGroup -Filter {whenCreated -lt $CreatedThreshold})
$ChangedGroups = @(Get-ADGroup -Filter {whenChanged -ge $ChangedThreshold})

#now we can test how many it returned
if($CreatedGroups.Count -lt 1)
{
    "No new groups have been created since $CreatedThreshold"
}
else
{
    $CreatedGroups |Select-Object Name, WhenCreated, WhenChanged
}
# And then the same thing for the changed groups
if($ChangedGroups.Count -ge 1)
{
    "No new groups have been created since $ChangedThreshold"
}
else
{
    $ChangedGroups | Select-Object Name, WhenChanged | Out-File C:\PScript\ChangedADGroups.txt
}
```

But its still not quite there on running properly as it stands it it displays all the groups in the domain as well as creates a csv with the same information.

Its still not displaying whenchanged and whencreated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to achieve. If what equals 0? Then do what? Please elaborate.

Comment: Absolutely, in other words if the results of whenCreated ADGroups = 0 then i want the script to move on and give me the list of ADGroups that have been changed.

If not then list both the created and changed in one output.

Comment: By "=0" you mean if the query does not return any matching groups? Because a value 0 for the `whenCreated` attribute doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes that is what i mean if the query does not return any groups.

Comment: @CharlesP change `whenCreated -lt` to `whenCreated -ge`, typo in my answer

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that seems to work great however it still does not list whenchanged on the csv file so i changed it to do a Out-File to a text instead of csv and it shows the heading at the top WhenChanged but no listings.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen what do you think it could be? You think i forgot a object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the returned groups to a variable before writing to a file, this way you can inspect how many results you got, before outputting to the file.

Additionally, avoid "broad" filters like `*` - it will make the domain controller return *all* groups, instead of just those you need:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$CreatedThreshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date
$ChangedThreshold = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date

$CreatedGroups = @(Get-ADGroups -Filter {whenCreated -ge $CreatedThreshold})

# now we can test how many it returned
if($CreatedGroups.Count -lt 1)
{
    "No new groups have been created since $CreatedThreshold" |Out-File C:\PScript\CreatedADGroups.txt
}
else
{
    $CreatedGroups |Select-Object Name,whenCreated |Out-File C:\PScript\CreatedADGroups.txt
}

# And then the same thing for the changed groups
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Mathias so the script runs but gives me the same output on the shell on text file.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: if you read the edit on the Code i went with your approach but it still not giving me whencreated and whenchanged.

Comment: @CharlesP You're echoing `$CreatedGroups` and writing `$ChangedGroups` to a file.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i added more code from your experience does it look right now?

Comment: @CharlesP Please don't change my (working) code to your own (non-working) code in edits. You still haven't managed to tell us exactly what it is you want - do you want to have both the created and changed groups output to the same file? Or to two different files?

Comment: @CharlesP What is changing the file name supposed to change about what goes into the file? Also, what Mathias said.

Comment: Guys i don't know how else to explain it. I have already said i do not know anything about Powershell i am taking two working scripts and trying to merge them into one. Mathias i apologize i thought i changing my original code. 

What i am looking for: 1.check for new groups created. 2.If no new groups where created 3.check groups that where changed. 4.export those changes to a file since the output will be large. And that's it, both the original scripts do this individually but i want to be able to run only one script.

Comment: To summarize: If new groups were created, export them to a file; if existing groups were modified: export them to another file. Correct?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers either that, or he's interested in the existing changed groups *only* if no new groups were found, I really can't tell

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers sorry it took me so ling to respond, i was able to what i was looking for.

Thank you for Evryeon's Help.

I am actually struggling with another script i wrote and as i am a total noob to PS i can't get this thing to "do while" and "until NULL"

Answer (score 0):

Before scripting or programming anything, you should get the goal very clear in your head. If you are not able to express what you want in natural language, there is no way you can program it in a computer language. This seems to be the problem here. If I understand your statement correctly:

> Absolutely, in other words if the results of whenCreated ADGroups = 0 then i want the script to move on and give me the list of ADGroups that have been changed. If not then list both the created and changed in one output.

You want to simply output **all** groups that have been created **or** changed. Once you can make such a clear statement of what you want, it should be pretty easy to write that.

Comment: I apologize if what i said isn't simple enough to understand for any reader that 0 = No Results.

These are two independent scripts that both run individually just fine, what i am trying to do if possible with the assistance of someone on here is merge both scripts into one. Giving it the logic that if it does not find any results of Groups created that it would move on to give me the groups that have been changed.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. Did you read and understand what I wrote?

Comment: The script seems to work with the help of Mathis and Others but am still unable to display when the group was created or changed. Looking at the code can you tell why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that [@Swonkie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35685599/1630171)'s interpretation is correct and you want all groups that were created or modified within the last 7 days, I would suggest something like this:

```
$threshold = (Get-Date).Date.AddDays(-7)

Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties whenCreated, whenChanged |
  Where-Object {
    $_.whenCreated -ge $threshold -or
    $_.whenChanged -ge $threshold
  } | Out-File 'C:\PScript\ChangedADGroups.txt'
```

It might be a good idea to select the properties you actually need and export the result as a CSV instead of writing a regular textfile, so you can easily import the file as a spreadsheet, e.g.:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties whenCreated, whenChanged |
  Where-Object {
    $_.whenCreated -ge $threshold -or
    $_.whenChanged -ge $threshold
  } |
  Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, whenCreated, whenChanged |
  Export-Csv 'C:\PScript\ChangedADGroups.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This didn't run for some reason.

Comment: @CharlesP saying it didn't run isn't useful if you want help with whatever thing caused it to not run. You need to say what didn't work, along with error messages. Add those to the OP.

Comment: I really recommend using `-Filter` instead of `where`.